# The line i'm animating using processing breaks on the bottom "bounce"

Tags: processing

This is the pixel object i'm using to emulate line motion.

```java
class LineDot{
 float x;
 float y;
 float yspeed=-1;
   LineDot(float a, float b){
 x=a;
 y=b;
 }
 float getX(){
   return x;
 }
 float getY(){
   return y;
 }
 void reverse(){
   yspeed*=-1;
 }
 void show(){
   stroke(255,255,255);
   line(x,y,x,y);
 }
 void move(){
   if(y<1){
     yspeed*=-1;
   }
   if(y>720){
     yspeed*=-1;
   }
   y=y+yspeed;

 }

}
```

This is how i'm creating the actual line using 1280 pixels and moving them up and down across the 1280x720 window.

```java
LineDot[] first = new LineDot[1280];
LineDot[] second = new LineDot[0];
void setup(){

  size(1280,720);

  for(int i = 0;i<first.length;i++){
    first[i]= new LineDot(i+1,(i+1)*0.5625);  
  }
  for(int i = 0;i<second.length;i++){
    second[i] = new LineDot(i+1,(i+30)*0.5625);
  }
}
void draw(){
  background(0,0,0);
  for(int i = 0;i<first.length;i++){
   first[i].show(); 
   first[i].move(); 
  }
  for(int i = 0;i<second.length;i++){
    second[i].show();
    second[i].move();
 }
```

}
When the line hits the bottom limit bottom for some reason 1 pixel out of about 10 will get separated the line by a pixel and the line becomes this weird almost striped line as shown here [image: Line Broken up] This is what it looks like when the line is broken up on the first bounce [image: First Bounce Break]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to do per-pixel manipulation then you need a capable environment so that you can see (and understand) what's happening. Here's your code, modified to run scaled 40 times:

```java
int w = 32;
int h = 16; 
LineDot[] first = new LineDot[w];
void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  for (int i = 0; i<first.length; i++) {
    first[i]= new LineDot(i+1, (i+1)*0.5625);
  }
  frameRate(2);
  noStroke();
}
void draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  scale(40);
  for (int i = 0; i<first.length; i++) {
    first[i].show(); 
    first[i].limitCheck();
    first[i].move();
  }
  stroke(128);
  strokeWeight(1/40);
  for(int i = 0; i <= h; i++) {
    line(0,i,w,i);
  }
}
class LineDot {
  float x;
  float y;
  float yspeed=-1;
  LineDot(float a, float b) {
    x=a;
    y=b;
  }
  float getX() {
    return x;
  }
  float getY() {
    return y;
  }
  void reverse() {
    yspeed*=-1;
  }
  void show() {
    fill(255);
    rect(x, y, 1, 1);
    fill(255,0,0);
    rect(x, y+yspeed, 1, 1);
  }
  void limitCheck() {
    if (y<1) {
      yspeed*=-1;
      //y = 1 - y;
    }
    if (y>h) {
      yspeed*=-1;
      //y = 2*h - y + 1;
    }
    fill(0,255,0);
    rect(x, y+yspeed, 1, 1);
  }
  void move() {
    y=y+yspeed;
  }
}
```

Some minor modifications:

- red: the pixel speed before touching the limits
- green: the speed the pixel will have after touching the limits f
- frameRate(2): reduce framerate to 2 frames per second so that we can see what's going on

The problem is not that lone pixel. As you can see, when the top side of the screen is touched (y<1) the line returns in a weird format. This is because the pixels go below y = 1 in pairs, but one of them is further away from 1 than the other. Despite that, when moving them you add 1 to both, resulting in them keeping their previous formation and not switching around.

If you uncomment the two lines in the code above you can see the fix (which also fixes your stray pixel)

```java
y = 1 - y;
```

and

```java
y = 2*h - y + 1;
```

We are essentially telling it that the location of the pixel also need to be fixed, and not just the speed. We are essentially reversing the amount the pixel travelled under 1 or over 720 to reflect, so a pixel that travelled to 0.3 (meaning it's under 1) should be moved to 0.7, while a pixel at 0.6 should be moved to 0.4.

This is your code with the two lines added in:

```java
LineDot[] first = new LineDot[1280];
LineDot[] second = new LineDot[0];
void setup() {

  size(1280, 720);

  for (int i = 0; i<first.length; i++) {
    first[i]= new LineDot(i+1, (i+1)*0.5625);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i<second.length; i++) {
    second[i] = new LineDot(i+1, (i+30)*0.5625);
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i<first.length; i++) {
    first[i].show(); 
    first[i].move();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i<second.length; i++) {
    second[i].show();
    second[i].move();
  }
}
class LineDot {
  float x;
  float y;
  float yspeed=-1;
  LineDot(float a, float b) {
    x=a;
    y=b;
  }
  float getX() {
    return x;
  }
  float getY() {
    return y;
  }
  void reverse() {
    yspeed*=-1;
  }
  void show() {
    stroke(255, 255, 255);
    line(x, y, x, y);
  }
  void move() {
    if (y<1) {
      yspeed*=-1;
      y = 1 - y;
    }
    if (y>720) {
      yspeed*=-1;
      y = 2*720 - y + 1;
    }
    y=y+yspeed;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i<first.length;i++){
 first[i]= new LineDot(i+1,(i+1)*0.5625);  
}
```

The value 0.5625 is the reason this is happening.

On changing it to 0.565, I was able to bring down the extra pixels to 4 per line.

Try some value after this and you might be able to eradicate extra pixels.

Hope this helps!!